# Javascript - How to listener a class parameter change from different callback function

Tags: javascript

I created class set a `setInterval()` and `callback()` to listener a parameter change.

For example:

```
class timer {
    constructor(sec){
        this.sec = sec;
    };
    start(callback){
        setInterval(() => {
            callback(this.sec--);
        },1000);
    }
}
```

New a the `timer` class and listener `sec` parameter change:

```
aTimer = new timer(50, callback);
callback(sec){
  console.log(sec);
}
```

But this `callback` can only be attached when the first call is made, this operation `callback` function is not flexible enough.

How to divide into two or more parts:

1. create a class and set parameter:

   `aTimer = new timer(50, callback);`
2. set listener `.on` callback function:

   `aTimer.on((sec)=>{ console.log(sec); });`

Some lib have a similar feature like `on`, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an `on` method that assigns to `this.secCallback`. Inside the interval, check if `this.secCallback` exists - if so, call it with the current `sec`:

```js
class timer {
  constructor(sec, callback) {
    this.sec = sec;
    setInterval(() => {
      if (this.secCallback) {
        this.secCallback(this.sec);
      }
      callback(this.sec--);
    }, 1000);
  }
  on(secCallback) {
    this.secCallback = secCallback;
  }
}
const aTimer = new timer(50, sec => console.log('start callback'));

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('new callback added');
  aTimer.on(sec => console.log('on callback'));
}, 2500);
```

Comment: The `setTimeout` was just an example to show that the listener is added asynchronously and still gets called normally whenever the interval fires - if you want to call `.on` synchronously, that would work just fine too.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you mean, is work, but I don't understand `this.secCallback = secCallback;` in `on(secCallback)`, how does this work? Why not `secCallback = this.secCallback;`

Comment: `secCallback` the variable name is the parameter passed to `on` - you need to assign that to a property of the instance, to `this.secCallback`, so that the `if (this.secCallback) {` test inside the constructor will be able to see that a second callback has been added, and thereby call it.

Comment: `secCallback = this.secCallback;` wouldn't do anything, because `this.secCallback` would always be `undefined` since it's never getting assigned to (and reassigning a parameter doesn't do anything anyway)

Comment: `this.secCallback = secCallback;` does it mean that `this.secCallback` is replaced by `secCallback;` ? `secCallback;` is a empty callback function?

Comment: `does it mean` Yes - `this.secCallback` is initially empty before `.on` is called. The standalone variable `secCallback` is whatever was passed to `.on`, which may be an empty function (but probably won't be).

Comment: oh..,  initially. I only call once when I call `on` on the outside(Will only be emptied once). this means that after `this.secCallback` is equal to `secCallback`, when I  change `this.secCallback` is equal to changed `secCallback` ?

Comment: Yes, after `this.secCallback = secCallback`, the parameter `secCallback` is assigned to a property of the instance